# Is there a way to prevent injection attacks when building a command-line from untrusted input in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a situation where a Bash script runs and parses a user-supplied JSON file using `jq`. Since it's supplied by the user, it's possible for them to include values in the JSON to perform an injection attack.

I'd like to know if there's a way to overcome this. Please note, the setup of: 'my script parsing a user-supplied JSON file' cannot be changed, as it's out of my control. Only thing I can control is the Bash script.

I've tried using `jq` with and without the `-r` flag, but in each case, I was successfully able to inject.

Here's what the Bash script looks like at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

eval "INCLUDES=($(cat user-supplied.json | jq '.Include[]'))"
CMD="echo Includes are: "
for e in "${INCLUDES[@]}"; do
    CMD="$CMD\\\"$e\\\" "
done

eval "$CMD"
```

And here is an example of a sample `user-supplied.json` file that demonstrates an injection attack:

```
{
  "Include": [
    "\\\";ls -al;echo\\\""
  ]
}
```

The above JSON file results in the output:
`Includes are: ""`
, followed by a directory listing (an actual attack would probably be something far more malicious).

What I'd like instead is something like the following to be outputted:
`Includes are: "\\\";ls -al;echo\\\""`

**Edit 1**

I used `echo` as an example command in the script, which probably wasn’t the best example, as then the solution is simply not using `eval`.

However the actual command that will be needed is `dotnet test`, and each array item from `Includes` needs to be passed as an option using `/p:<Includes item>`. What I was hoping for was a way to globally neutralise injection regardless of the command, but perhaps that’s not possible, ie, the technique you go for relies heavily on the actual command.

Comment: If all you want is to print the contents of the `Include` array, why are you `eval`ing (twice)?

Comment: don't use eval. problem solved

Comment: `INCLUDES=( $(jq '.Include[]' user-supplied.json) )` does what you want, without executing any user-supplied input. You may need to adjust some of `jq`'s options to get the shell array that you want, but nothing requiring `eval`.

Comment: @BenjaminW Please see Edit 1. Is it still possible to not use eval?

Comment: @oguzismail As above ^.

Comment: @AjLearning, ...there is, to a reasonable first approximation, **never** a good reason to use `eval`. The question shouldn't be "how can I make this code that uses eval safe?", it should be "how can I perform this operation without using eval?".

Comment: BTW, just to be careful, what's your platform? I've seen some bash-for-Windows builds (maybe cygwin?) where process substitution (the `<(...)` construct) didn't work correctly, but if you're on a proper UNIX-y platform, that should be moot.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy From memory, it’s a dotnet:2-sdk Docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `eval` for `dotnet test` either. Many bash extensions not present in POSIX sh exist *specifically* to make `eval` usage unnecessary; if you *think* you need `eval` for something, you should provide enough details to let us explain why it isn't actually required. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- Syntax below is bash-only; the shell *must* be bash, not /bin/sh

include_args=( )
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a includes < <(jq -r '.Include[]' user-supplied.json && printf '\0')
for include in "${includes[@]}"; do
  include_args+=( "/p:$include" )
done

dotnet test "${include_args[@]}"
```

To speak a bit to what's going on:

- `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arrayname` reads up to the next NUL character in stdin (`-d` specifies a single character to stop at; since C strings are NUL-terminated, the first character in an empty string is a NUL byte), splits on newlines, and puts the result into `arrayname`.

  The shorter way to write this in bash 4.0 or later is `readarray -t arrayname`, but that doesn't have the advantage of letting you detect whether the program generating the input failed: Because we have the `&& printf '\0'` attached to the `jq` code, the NUL terminator this `read` expects is only present if `jq` succeeds, thus causing the `read`'s exit status to reflect success only if `jq` reported success as well.
- `< <(...)` is redirecting stdin from a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), which is replaced with a filename which, when read from, returns the output of running the code `...`.
- The reason we can set `include_args+=( "/p:$include" )` and have it be exactly the same as `include_args+=( /p:"$include" )` is that the quotes are read by the shell itself and used to determine where to perform string-splitting and globbing; they're *not* persisted in the generated content (and thus later passed to `dotnet test`).

Some other useful references:

- [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!* -- explains in depth why you can't store commands in strings *without* using `eval`, and describes better practices to use instead (storing commands in functions; storing commands in arrays; etc).
- [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048): *Eval command and security issues* -- Goes into more detail on why `eval` is widely frowned on.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I’ll try this and accept if it works.

Comment: I’m getting a “syntax error near unexpected token ‘<‘ “ ?

Comment: I've tried to expand with explanation and references. Let me know if there's anything more that would be needed to constitute a complete and full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. It works. Just had to make one change which is remove the `-r` option from the call to `jq`, as the quotes are needed for the argument to `/p:`, which has the form `/p:<key>="<include>"`.

Comment: @AjLearning, when you're entering it at bash, do you do `/pkey="include"`, or `'/pkey="include"'`? When content is evaluated as code (as when it's manually typed, but *not* when it comes from a parameter expansion), unless you escape your double quotes (as by putting single-quotes around them or backslashes just before them), they just get removed by bash and not passed to `dotnet test` at all.

Comment: @AjLearning, ...it's helpful to compare the trace logs emitted with `set -x` before a successful manual invocation to the ones emitted by `bash -x yourscript`, as that'll let you know when two quoting mechanisms actually evaluate to the same underlying string.

Comment: Interesting you mention that because I had tried `set -x` to se what was happening and it suggested the option being passed to `dotnet test` was `‘/p:Include=“some-item%2csome-other-item%2c”’`. While I did construct the string within the double quotes, I’m not sure how it ended up putting the entire option in single quotes automatically.

Comment: As I was mentioning above, `set -x` emits *a printable representation of* your real string. If the real string has spaces or quotes of a different type, then the printable representation needs to quote them in some way to show that they're passed as literal values and aren't shell syntax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191549/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ajlearning).

Comment: Also since I had to concat multiple items together within the one double quoted string, I ended up using `jq` with the `-r` option after all.

Comment: *nod*; this is a place where showing what you actually wanted to run in the question would have made it stronger (less mind-reading required).

Comment: Agreed. Was trying to be general so that the solution could be applied to any command (not just `dotnet test` with the required options), but being specific in this case certainly would’ve made it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `eval` at all.

```
INCLUDES=( $(jq '.Include[]' user-supplied.json) )
echo "Includes are: "
for e in "${INCLUDES[@]}"; do
  echo "$e"
done
```

The worst that can happen is that the unquoted command substitution may perform word-splitting or pathname expansion where you don't want it (which is a problem in your original as well), but there's no possibility for arbitrary command execution.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use string-splitting here, vs `readarray -t includes < <(jq -r ...)`? (For other readers of this comment, see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) for context).

Comment: I'm punting on the question of what `INCLUDES` should actually contain. It's quite possible that no array is even needed for whatever the OP ultimately wants.

Comment: @chepner Please see Edit 1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Perhaps I’m missing something since my Bash skills aren’t that great, but I thought eval is needed to execute a built up string? The full command string that’s built might end up looking like: dotnet test /p:”item1” /p:”item2”, where each of the items comes from Includes.

Comment: @AjLearning, you shouldn't build commands as strings at all, you should build them as arrays. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).